# least cost path between multiple points: obtain a travelling time matrix based on cost raster

Tags: qgis-3, least-cost

I'm new to GIS and would like to obtain a matrix with travelling times between multiple facilities. I already have a friction surface with travel times.

The plugin Least Cost Path seems to be very interesting, but unfortunately, you can only enter one start point and I want to find routes between around 150 facilities. Moreover, the algorithm will only return a route between the start point and closest end point. I tried to figure out the code on GitHub, but because of my very limited programming skills, the code is too complex for me.

Another post asks this question: [Least cost path between various points QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/173064/least-cost-path-between-various-points-qgis/173591#173591). 
The piece of code there might help me further as well, but I don't know what the code does exactly and because I already have my cost raster, I think I should adapt the code. However, I can't ask anything as a comment since I'm a new user.

Does anyone know other ways to obtain such a travelling time matrix or how I can use the two options above?
I don't necessarily need the routes itself, only the related travel times.

kind regards,
Dana

Comment: Have you looked at the Network Analysis tools available in the Processing Toolbox? `Shortest path (point to point)` looks like it would do what you want.

Comment: the tool does not use a file of points, you have to point them on the map. So this would take a long time for many routes. Furthermore, I'm sturggling with my network, that is why I'd like to use a raster instead.